# Qooxdoo - "VirtualTree" and missing "cellrenderer"

Tags: qooxdoo, cellrenderer

I am trying to create editable tree widget. There are many samples how to make editable columns for Table, for example by using cellrenderer and propertyCellRendererFactoryFunc - which is quite awesome. Unfortunately I can't find any useful example for VirtualTree/Tree. Is it even possible to create one without deep Tree source code editing?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach for VirtualTree:

- VirtualTree uses normal widgets for the tree items, so the idea is to taylor the way these items are created, in order to modify their appearance.
- This is achieved through a delegate. Use *tree.setDelegate()* to set a custom delegate on a tree.
- The delegate itself can be a native JS object (map). It has to conform to the [IVirtualTreeDelegate interface](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.0.x/apiviewer/#qx.ui.tree.core.IVirtualTreeDelegate), meaning the delegate object exposes some methods from a predefined set (like 'bindItem', 'createItem', ...). See the code of [this demo](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.0.x/demobrowser/#virtual~Tree_Dynamic.html) for a general example.
- In your case, you want to provide a [*createItem*](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.0.x/apiviewer/#qx.ui.tree.core.IVirtualTreeDelegate~createItem) method in your delegate, along with any other supporting methods (e.g. *bindItem*). There is a somewhat more [complicated example](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.0.x/demobrowser/#virtual~Tree_Columns.html) that does that, which uses an instance of itself as the delegate.

HTH